# A question about udevadm trigger for power-switch

Tags: power-management, shutdown, devices

I use ubuntu 20.04. Today my computer shut down automatically twice. I entered 'journalctl' for checking and got the result 'systemd-logind[761]: Power key pressed.' I googled this result and found out that it's triggered by the power button on the physical device [(Similar issue)](https://superuser.com/questions/1071800/explanation-of-systemd-logind-in-auth-log). However, when I entered the code mentioned in the content for checking, I found out some device that are not related to the power button. Is that normal?

`udevadm trigger -v -n -g power-switch | xargs -i cat {}/../name`

```
Power Button
Video Bus
Power Button
Sleep Button
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10
HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
HDA Intel PCH Line
HDA Intel PCH Line Out
HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
Eee PC WMI hotkeys
```

Comment: Has the power button gone bad? Is the computer over heating?

Comment: Power button have nothing wrong. I wasn't install sensors before, so i don't know if that is  question of over heating. Maybe that is the question what is happening. thank you.